# Linked List code samples

Tags: java, linked-list

What do the following snippets of code result in?

Suppose x is a linked-list link

```
a.   x.setNext( x.getNext().getNext() );


b.   t.setNext (x.getNext());
     x.setNext (t);

c.   x.setNext(t);
     t.setNext(x.getNext());
```

Comment: Add the language tag.

Comment: This looks suspiciously like homework. Stack Overflow is not a "please do my homework for me" site.

Comment: Its material for exam review. Not worth ANY credit. didnt know stack overflow was a site full of 'administrators who care'

Comment: What do you think those snippets do?  What about linked-list setters and getters don't you understand that makes them unclear?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to solve these are through diagrams - it'll help you understand so much so easily. Represent each node through simple boxes & connect them up with arrows. Then execute each method & follow it through.

Here's the first one:

Assume a normal linked-list with nodes x,y,z connected in sequence:

[image: Linked List with three elements]

- `x.getNext()` would result in `node y`.
- `y.getNext()` would result in `node z`.
- `z.getNext()` would result in `null`, since there are no more nodes after it.
- Likewise, `x.getNext().getNext()` would be asking the "node after the next", which is `node z`
- `setNext(n)` obviously sets the next node as `n` (Any previous values are replaced)

So in the statement `x.setNext(x.getNext().getNext());`, you know `x.getNext().getNext()` becomes `node z`. Thus you've `x.setNext(z);`, which would result in the below:

[image: Linked List with mid-delOperation]

So, now you've nodes x & y pointing to z. `Node x` can no longer point to `node y`, since you have set it to point to `node z`. Now, when it comes to linked-lists, you would only have the starting node saved, i.e. `node x`. You'll never have references to other nodes. So, you essentially have lost `node y`. There is no way to traverse/navigate to it from the start/x:

- `x.getNext()` results in `node z`
- `z.getNext()` results in `null`

So, since `node y` is lost, your linked list becomes this:

[image: Linked List with two nodes (one deleted)]

In short, `x.setNext(x.getNext().getNext());` would mean to delete the node after x. Hopefully you can figure out the other two.